# On QuantLib's date class and C++11/boost Chrno

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, c++-chrono, quantlib

Is there a programatic and convenient way to convert from `C++11` or `Boost's` `Chorno` to `Quantlib's` date class format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know hardly anything about Quantlib's date class format.  However a quick search indicated that it uses 1899-12-30 as its day number 0, its epoch.

Although not specified by C++11, every implementation I know of for `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point` uses 1970-01-01 as the day 0 epoch.  And there are exactly 25,569 days between these two epochs.

This paper:

> [chrono-Compatible Low-Level Date Algorithms](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html)

Contains algorithms for converting year/month/day triples to and from a count of days before and after 1970-01-01.  Using these algorithms I believe you could shift the epoch by 25,569 days in order to convert a count of days between one epoch and the other, and subsequently provide the conversion you are seeking.  But this is a roll-your-own solution, not a pre-packaged one.

Comment: this is genius by the way

Comment: Day 0 for Excel and COM's Variant Date is 1899-12-30. The original Day 0 of 1899-12-31 had to be revised because the Microsoft code worked with 1900 as a leap year (oops!).  So Excel/COM dates are QuantLib dates plus 1.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the numbers accordingly.